# Persisting to Kerberized HDFS from Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, authentication, hdfs, kerberos

my current set-up:

- Spark version 2.3.1 (Cluster running on Windows) uses Spark secret (basic).
- Hdfs (Cluster running on Linux) Kerberized.

*Not ideal! but there's a good reason why I can't use the same set of machines for both clusters.*

I am able to read/ write to Hdfs from a standalone Spark application but when I try to run similar code on the Spark cluster I get an authentication error.

> java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via: [TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details....

Comment: Pass keytab and pricipal. -–conf keytab=path_to_keytab -–conf principal=xxxxxxx

Comment: Thanks Kishore, that's been done unfortunately but still no luck! works well in standalone mode but not in cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your other cluster node? Which user running spark in cluster mode? Does that user has permission to access keytab? I think it can be permission issue or some typo.